# Lowest Common Ancestor of a Binary Search Tree code doesn't pass

Tags: binary-tree

can anyone help me with this code? I cannot figure out where I'm blocked.

Given a binary search tree (BST), find the lowest common ancestor (LCA) of two given nodes in the BST.

```
TreeNode* lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {
   TreeNode* res=NULL;
   int i=0;
   postTrav(root,p,q,res,i);
   return res;
}

void postTrav(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q,TreeNode* res,int& i){

    if(!root){
        return;
    }
    postTrav(root->left,p,q,res,i);
    postTrav(root->right,p,q,res,i);
    if(root==p||root==q){
        i++;
    }
    if(i==2){
        res=root;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a logic bug in addition to this, but, because C [I assume] is call-by-value, setting `res` and `i` are changed local to a given function invocation, but then discarded.  You'll need to pass around some addresses, as below.  Especially, note that `res` is now `TreeNode **` in `postTrav`.

```
TreeNode *
lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode *root, TreeNode *p, TreeNode *q)
{
    TreeNode *res = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    postTrav(root, p, q, &res, &i);

    return res;
}

void
postTrav(TreeNode *root, TreeNode *p, TreeNode *q, TreeNode **res, int *i)
{

    if (!root) {
        return;
    }

    postTrav(root->left, p, q, res, i);
    postTrav(root->right, p, q, res, i);

    if (root == p || root == q) {
        *i++;
    }
    if (*i == 2) {
        *res = root;
        *i++;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above code is fine.  But, whenever, I have a function that needs to return or maintain two or more values [in parallel], a technique I use is to create an additional "traversal" or "helper" struct that simplifies the argument passing.

If you needed an additional variable that needed to be modified/maintained across the calls, instead of adding an additional argument to all functions, it becomes easy/easier to just add another variable to the struct.  This works particularly well when you're building up your logic as you go along.

Here's the code for the refinement.  Notice that fewer arguments need to be pushed/popped.  And, this probably executes as fast or faster than the original.  Also, for me, `trav->res` seems a bit cleaner than `*res`

```
// traversal "helper" struct
struct _traverse {
    TreeNode *p;                        // not modified
    TreeNode *q;                        // not modified

    TreeNode *res;                      // result
    int i;                              // depth

    // add more variables here as desired ...
#ifdef WANT_TRAVERSAL_STATISTICS
    int visited_count;                  // number of nodes we visited
#endif
};
typedef struct _traverse Traverse;

TreeNode *
lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode *root, TreeNode *p, TreeNode *q)
{
    Traverse trav;

    trav.p = p;
    trav.q = q;

    trav.res = NULL;
    trav.i = 0;

#ifdef WANT_TRAVERSAL_STATISTICS
    trav.visited_count = 0;
#endif

    postTrav(root, &trav);

#ifdef WANT_TRAVERSAL_STATISTICS
    printf("Visited %d Nodes\n",trav.visited_count);
#endif

    return trav.res;
}

void
postTrav(TreeNode *root, Traverse *trav)
{

    if (!root) {
        return;
    }

#ifdef WANT_TRAVERSAL_STATISTICS
    trav->visited_count += 1;
#endif

    postTrav(root->left, trav);
    postTrav(root->right, trav);

    if (root == trav->p || root == trav->q) {
        trav->i++;
    }
    if (trav->i == 2) {
        trav->res = root;
        trav->i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the property of BST. postTrav should be like this:

```
TreeNode* postTrav(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q,)
{

if (root == NULL||p==NULL||q==NULL) return NULL;
int n1=p->data;
int n2=q->data;
while (root != NULL)
{
     // If both n1 and n2 are smaller than root, then LCA lies in left
    if (root->data > n1 && root->data > n2)
       root = root->left;

    // If both n1 and n2 are greater than root, then LCA lies in right
    else if (root->data < n1 && root->data < n2)
       root = root->right;

    else break;
}
return root;
```

}